# Array of objects placement inside react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, scope

I'm trying to build functionality on a webpage that plays mp3's using React. I have an array of objects that hold each song, album cover, artist, title.

I'm trying to figure out where this gets placed in a React class component.

What I would like to do is pass the mp3 down as props to the player component but I'm not able to read the object inside of the array using this line:

The error I'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
console.log(this.playlist[0].src);
```

Below is a snapshot of my Music Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Player from '../Player';
import './Music.css';


class Music extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            IsPlaying: false,
            currentImageShown: ''
        }
        let playlist = [
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            },
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            },
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            }
        ];
    }

    handlePlayControlClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('play button clicked');

        // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        console.log(this.playlist[0].src);
    }
    handlePauseControlClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('pause button clicked');
    }
    handleForwardControlClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('forward clicked');
    }
    handleBackwardControlClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('backward clicked');
    }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Player 
                        onPlayClick={this.handlePlayControlClick}
                        onPauseClick={this.handlePauseControlClick}
                        onForwardControlClick={this.handleForwardControlClick}
                        onBackwardControlClick={this.handleBackwardControlClick}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        };
    }

export default Music;
```

Is let playlist = [array of {objects}] in the wrong spot? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not add playlist to state?

Comment: Good point, I couldn't decide whether to keep the playlist static and then pass one object into state or put the entire playlist in state and add a key to each object and call it something like selected: false. I think both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `playlist` is in the incorrect spot.  It's a local variable in the constructor, therefore, it's not visible outside of the constructor method.

If it's a static list, you can make `playlist` a class member.

```
class Music extends Component {
    playlist = [
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            },
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            },
            {
                src: 'mymp3',
                songPicture: 'someimage',
                author: 'artistname',
                title: 'songname'
            }
    ];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            IsPlaying: false,
            currentImageShown: ''
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since playlist is just constant data (only reading in component), You can keep it above the class declaration.

```
const playlist = [{}, {}];

class Music extends Component {}

// console.log(playlist[0].src);
```